# Maven not working?

Tags: maven, maven-2

Initially I used maven with proxy and it was working fine. Now I don't need the proxy, so I edited the settings.xml to not use proxy. After that, Maven does not connect to the Internet to download repos. I tried reinstalling, but still getting the same problem. I even tried IDEs like eclipse and IDEA but the problem was still there. How do I resolve this?

`mvn --version`

```
Apache Maven 2.2.1 (rdebian-8)
Java version: 1.6.0_24
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre
Default locale: en_IN, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux" version: "3.2.0-31-generic-pae" arch: "i386" Family: "unix"
```

`mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=org.sonatype.mavenbook.simple -DartifactId=simple -DpackageName=org.sonatype.mavenbook -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT`

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Searching repository for plugin with prefix: 'archetype'.
[INFO] org.apache.maven.plugins: checking for updates from central
```

Nothings happens after this.

Comment: If you have all dependencies in your local repository maven will not download artifacts from repositories. What does it mean "not connect to internet to download repo" ? It will only download things which are not in your local repository. If everything is there Maven has no reason to download something. Do you get any error messages ?

Comment: The error is it does not finish generating a project...it infinitely pauses at this point "[INFO] org.apache.maven.plugins: checking for updates from central"

Answer (score 0):

All things considered, my initial thought is this is a connection issue since it fails to work after removing the proxy settings. Are you able to ping or curl the repository being scanned?

Comment: @user20855 And you're confident the use of ping/curl is not influenced by any other proxy settings (not related to Maven)?